# bind json to html and post in axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The backend is sending data that contains JSON responses. I have no issue dealing with the values in the response except one value "meta" that comes in a JSON object. I need to bind it in HTML input and if modified I should send it in JSON.

Here is the response

```
{
  "client_wallet_balance":150,
  "meta":"{\"accessToken\":\"eyJpdiI6IjhsQWpaa1hJalNJTkVnjEyMiJ9\"}",
  "is_third_party":1
}
```

I should bind it in the HTML

```
<textarea
   name="merchant_token"
   class="mt-3 w-1/2"
   v-model="JSON.parse(clientData.meta).accessToken"
    >
 </textarea>
```

The data is sent all at once with the other values bound in the HTML. The issue I am facing here is that the meta isn't updated to the new one.

```
async submit() {
      const response = await update.call(this, this.clientData);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You ought to use a `computed` method with `set` and `get` for your dynamic `meta` data, or use a `data` property which gets modified by the `axios` handler via a `method`. It is bad form ( perhaps invalid also ) to do computations and transformations of data in the `v-model` attribute itself.

Here would be the `method` approach:

```
<template>
  <textarea
    name="merchant_token"
    class="mt-3 w-1/2"
    v-model="decoded_meta" >
  </textarea>
</template>

<script>
// ...
  data() {
    return {
      decoded_meta: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updated_meta(data) {
      this.decoded_meta = JSON.parse(data.meta).accessToken
    }
  }
// ...
</script>
```

Then, after you get your return payload from `axios`, send it through `updated_meta` as well.

Comment: When I get the response from the backend I save the data in `data` property called clientData, this happens in `watch` once the component is loaded. Now I tried to implement your solution, I added the `updated_meta` in watch to take clientData but I receive an error  Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: `this.updated_meta(data)` would be called within your `then()` from `axios`, and in that case you may need to `const vue = this` and use `vue.updated_meta` inside `then()` ... can update my answer to include that.

Comment: Still not working. I tried with computed but didn't work. Can you show how that works in computing? Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you post a more complete code snippet? When you mention `watch` and whatnot, it makes me wonder what other dynamics at play.